# Get an array from SQL Server with PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, react-native

I need to draw graph in my react native app.

The problem: when I saw some examples I found that BarChat of react-native-svg-charts is expecting an array like :[1,2,3] but the result that I get from my PHP file is like [{"ChiffreAffaire":"4800.00"}]

So what is the solution?

The example of barchart I found:

```
const barData = [ 14, -1, 100, -95, -94, -24, -8, 85, -91, 35, -53, 53, -78, 66, 96, 33, -26, -32, 73, 8 ]
return (
            <BarChart
                style={ { height: 200 } }
                data={ barData }
                svg={{
                    fill: 'green',
                }}
                contentInset={ { top: 30, bottom: 30 } }
                { ...this.props }
            >
                <Grid/>
            </BarChart>
        )
```

My php file :

```
<?php
$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Netos_DB","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
$sql = "select  ChiffreAffaire from V502_client where Mois=2 and Annee=2020 "; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql  );
while( $row[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $Item = $row;
    $json = json_encode($Item);
}
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {` That returns an array you dont have to use the `[]`

Comment: So I will have result like {"ChiffreAffaire":"4800.00"} but I doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the value, then only add the value to your Items array. Also build the array in the while loop `$Item[] = .....` and then echo the JSON string after the while loop is completed and the array is completly built.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $Item[] = $row['ChiffreAffaire'];
}
echo json_encode($Item);
```